# How to GET actors that containing nationality like argentine sort by fullName: error when typing in url postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I want to get only actors that containing nationality e.g "Argentine" sort by fullName in order to ascending.

This is my Actor Routes.js:

```
  router.get("/ask/actorsask", actorsCtrl.getActorByNationality);
```

And this is my Actor controller.js

```
  export const getActorByNationality = async (req,res) =>{

     try{

    var regExpTerm = new RegExp(req.query.ask,'i');

     var regExpSearch = 
      [{
        nationality: {$regex: regExpTerm}
     }];


      const actors = await Actor.find({$or: regExpSearch})
     .where('nationality').equals({$or: regExpSearch}).sort({fullName: 1})
       .exec(callback);

     res.status(200).send(actors);


      }catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({ mensaje: e });
     }
   };
```

this is my Actor's model.js:

```
     const actorSchema = new Schema({

           fullName: String,

           birthDate: Date,

           genre: String,

           nationality: String

       },
    {
    
       timestamps:{required: true},
       versionKey: false

      }
   )
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
                [ {
                    "_id": "6004b4323265a91b18f96d39",
                     "fullName": "Ana Lopez",
                     "birthDate": "1993-02-10T17:00:00.000Z",
                      "genre": "female",
                      "nationality": "argentine",
                      "createdAt": "2021-01-17T22:03:30.011Z",
                       "updatedAt": "2021-01-17T22:03:30.011Z"
                      },

                  {
                    "_id": "6004b348b1cd7f28c8d5569d",
                    "fullName": "Omar Aparicio",
                    "birthDate": "1994-08-10T14:00:00.032Z",
                     "genre": "male",
                     "nationality": "argentine",
                     "createdAt": "2021-01-17T21:59:36.185Z",
                     "updatedAt": "2021-01-17T21:59:36.185Z"
                   },
                     ]
```

but the real output is this one:

```
                [
                 {
                   "_id": "6004b348b1cd7f28c8d5569d",
                   "fullName": "Omar Aparicio",
                   "birthDate": "1994-08-10T14:00:00.032Z",
                   "genre": "male",
                   "nationality": "argentine",
                   "createdAt": "2021-01-17T21:59:36.185Z",
                   "updatedAt": "2021-01-17T21:59:36.185Z"
                  },
                    {
                       "_id": "6004b4323265a91b18f96d39",
                       "fullName": "Ana Lopez",
                       "birthDate": "1993-02-10T17:00:00.000Z",
                       "genre": "female",
                       "nationality": "argentine",
                       "createdAt": "2021-01-17T22:03:30.011Z",
                       "updatedAt": "2021-01-17T22:03:30.011Z"
                     },
                      {
                       "_id": "6004b4423265a91b18f96d3a",
                       "fullName": "nishimura sam",
                       "birthDate": "1978-09-22T16:00:00.000Z",
                       "genre": "male",
                       "nationality": "albanese",
                       "createdAt": "2021-01-17T22:03:46.143Z",
                       "updatedAt": "2021-01-17T22:13:20.411Z"
                        }
                   ]
```

I'm typing this as url in postman selecting as GET method:

```
               http://localhost:4000/api/actors/ask/actorsask?nationality="argentine"
```

I think problem it's on actor routes.js or actor controller.js in getActorByNationality method but I don't know how to fix it.

¿What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was some code copy from another source. I fixed some issues. Try with this version.

```
export const getActorByNationality = async (req,res) =>{

  try{

  const findCond = req.query.nationality? {nationality: req.query.nationality}: {}

   const actors = await Actor.find(findCond)
    .sort({fullName: 1})
    .exec(callback);

  res.status(200).send(actors);


   }catch (e) {
     res.status(500).send({ mensaje: e });
  }
};
```

Comment: How to typing the url with req.query in postman in the case for this web service?, I type this: http://localhost:4000/api/actors/ask/actorsask?nationality=argentine and I've got as error: '500 Internal Server Error'

Comment: Your url looks good to me. Can you console.log the error and see where exactly it is failing in your code?

Comment: callback is not defined but I've fixed. I deleted ".exec(callback)" and it works.